# Athena query submit via shell script

Tags: bash, unix, amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I am executing a shell script In an emr cluster with script-runner   to run a Athena query for all data dates in a Month by using aws Athena --query string.
Once I submitted a step, query is being executed for 10 days  and the corresponding query Id is displayed in sysout log and the step moves to completed status.

Question:
How to make the job step to execute for all days  and then make job status completed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for us to be able to answer. Can you provide a simple example of what you are currently doing and how you would like to modify it? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is using Athena mandatory in your case ? Because I'd think a spark step querying your glue catalog would be less expensive, easier and maybe faster. Also, why execute the Athena query in an EMR cluster and not on a simple EC2 instance ?